# Parallels error: "Image BSS overlaps adjacent EFI memory region"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, parallels

I'm using parallels an an m1 macbook pro and the virtualization of ubuntu 20.04 worked perfectly fine until today. I can't launch it and it tells me that "Image BSS overlaps adjacent EFI memory region".
Does someone know how to fix it ?

I also can't create a new virtual machine since it prints the same error when I try to launch the new one.

Comment: Same issue started happening today, thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 4):

Booting into an older version of the Kernel allowed me to safely access the VM after this happened to me. Although I also was running out of disk and needed to increase the amount of disk space allocated to the virtual machine.

I believe the latest version of the Ubuntu 20.04 kernel may not work on Parallels for now. Specifically `linux-image-5.13.0-35-generic` gave me trouble and booting into `linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic` worked fine.

The steps I took were

1. Attempt to boot into VM. It should hang at `Parallels error: "Image BSS overlaps adjacent EFI memory region"`
2. Go to `Actions > Stop` [image]
3. Attempt to boot into the VM once again, at this point it should allow you to select `Advanced options for Ubuntu`. Select this.
4. In this screen select an older kernel version to boot into. I didn't have to boot into Recovery Mode.
5. Uninstall the breaking kernel. I just did `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.13.0-35-generic`.

It should be noted that I had older kernel versions available. If you've also deleted older kernel version preemptively, then I'm not sure what can be done.

Comment: Thank you.  The "Stop", and then  Advanced, selecting the old kernel did the trick.  Since Parallels is commercial software, have you attempted to report this?

Comment: Update:  No need to report, updating to Parallels 17.1.2 seems to allow the VM to boot again with e.g. `5.13.0-39` kernel.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. FWIW same deal with VMware fusion - can boot -30, but not anything newer. Presumably they'll fix it soon too I hope.